# Title bar showing when no title is entered

Tags: codenameone

This is something that occurred within the last 24 hours that did not beforehand.
If I create a new `Form` with not title (so, `Form hi = new Form();`) the bar on top still appears.
[image: Bar shadow]

Is there a way to get rid of it?
This only happens on devices (Android) and not on the emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into this to and contacted support.

turns out that there is now a default border for the `TitleArea` UIID for the drop shadow effect on Android. You can disable this by overriding the `TitleArea` UIID and defining an empty border.